# Sticky footer does not work with IE8

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I have a page with a sticky footer. Works fine with Firefox but not with IE8. The page is built on Blueprint and I used the `margin-top: -48px;` technique.

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#footer_container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -48px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a doctype as the very first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Without it, IE is using [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).